# Jupyter Notebook kernal is not connecting when lunching from power shell

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I am facing this strange issue, when I am directly launching Jupyter Notebook from CMD it is running properly but when I am launching it from powershell it is not able to connect to the Kernal.

Also I have pip installed Plotly, when I am importing it in powershell, I am able to import properly, but the same this in jupyter, it is saying no module name Plotly (with proper casing)?

jupyter 4.4.0 and Python 3.6.5, iPython is already up to date

[image: issue on powershell] [image: same file with jupyter cmd]
I am unable to find out what might be causing this issue.
or something to inspect the kernals.
Can someone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try this on powershell `python -m notebook`

Comment: no improvement, I have updated the question, that might give more info

Answer (score 0):

according to [github issue](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter_console/issues/158) try downgrading prompt-toolkit to the version 1.0.15

`pip3 install 'prompt-toolkit<2.0.0,>=1.0.15' --force-reinstall`

Python 3.6.5
jupyter 1.0.0
jupyter-client 5.2.3
jupyter-console 5.2.0
jupyter-core 4.4.0
ipython 6.4.0

You can even try upgrading iPython

`pip3 install --upgrade --user ipython`

Comment: how should I downgrade it to the given versions, can you also give the github link

Comment: I have jupyter 4.4.0 and Python 3.6.5, iPython is already uptodate

Comment: did you try downgrading `prompt-toolkit`